# "The attachment [.../1.jpg] doesn't exist!" error when trying to send attachment using sendmail

Tags: shell, sendmail

I'm using the following command line in order to send an email with attachment from my Raspberry Pi (running raspbian):

```
sendEmail -f myemail@gmail.com -t someemail@gmail.com \
-u Mail Subject -m "Mail Message" \
-s smtp.gmail.com \
-o tls=yes \
-a "/home/pi/Desktop/Track/1.jpg" \
-xu myUserName -xp myPassword
```

and I get the following error:

```
Apr 07 15:19:52 raspberrypi sendEmail[19095]: ERROR => The attachment [/home/pi/Desktop/Track/1.jpg] doesn't exist!
```

(The image 1.jpg is, of course, does exist in this path).

Using the command without the `-a` works fine. I tried using a relative path but it didn't help. There is obviously something very basic I'm missing here but I could not find a good guide online on how it should be done.

Comment: check the permissions on the file, and on **all** directories in that path. They need to be something like `755`. For example, `ls -ld /home/pi` should return `drwxr-x-r-x ...`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Indeed permission problem.